# IIs 7 Management Service

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7

I have a site in my office and i want to administrate remotely from home.
Searching on internet said that i have to enable something in MANAGMENT SERVICE.

In my IIS dont exist **MANAGEMENT SERVICE**

How can install it.

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of research for the same problem I can tell you that the specified feature is not available in the "client" editions of Windows (i.e. Windows 7).